# How can only 2 phases of a 3 phase power system be used to power a load?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, power, dirac-delta-distributions

When looking at 2 of the 3 phases on a graph, there's a point where they're both positive or both negative. How does one of the phases act as a return path?

Comment: Even with a single phase, there's a point in the graph where the voltage goes to 0. You just don't get any power at that instant in time.

Comment: True but for example, 120V single phase, a neutral is used that acts as the return path for current.

Comment: There's still no power delivered when the hot line is at the same potential as neutral. The load just has to work with regular instants of 0 power. How it does that depends what kind of load.

Comment: Thanks, I understand your point. But when you use 2 phases say at 277V, how does current flow through one phase and return through the other if both phases are positive (or negative)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even with a single phase, there's a point in the graph where the voltage goes to 0. You just don't get any power at that instant in time. The load just has to work with regular instants of 0 power. How it does that depends what kind of load.

> But when you use 2 phases say at 277V, how does current flow through one phase and return through the other if both phases are positive (or negative)?

As long as the voltages are not equal, there is a potential difference between them, and so power can be delivered.

If you hook up a 1 ohm resistor between a 1000 V source and a 1001 V source, then 1 A will be passed through the resistor and 1 W will be consumed by the resistor.

Comment: I think I'm understanding, so because the phases are 120 degrees apart that creates a potential difference between the 2 phases that allows one to act as a return path? I understand how this potential difference is maintained in a 240V split phase system since they're 180 degrees out of phase, but not entirely for 3 phase.